# AngularJS Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object' and Parse Query

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, ionic2

So when I try to take my data from my parse query and put it in my array I end up with this error Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. My Code for the Html and ts file are below. And my model file is also below. Is there a better way to display this data in the list?

Html:

```
<ion-header>

<ion-navbar>
<ion-title button-right>Trade</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addTrade()">
     <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
<ion-content>
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
 <ion-list [virtualScroll]="items">      
  <ion-item *virtualItem="let item">
     {{ item.offering }}   {{item.needs}}   
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and my ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Items} from "../../trade-model";
var Parse = require('parse');

/*
Generated class for the Trade page.

See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
selector: 'page-trade',
templateUrl: 'trade.html'
 })
export class TradePage {
searchQuery: string = ''
items: Items ={
offering: [],
needs: []

}


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

Parse.initialize('blankedout','unused', "blankedout");
Parse.serverURL = 'blankedout';


}
ionViewWillEnter(){
this.initializeItems()
}

ionViewWillLeave(){

}
initializeItems() {
var this_ref = this
var Trade = Parse.Object.extend("Trade")
var query = new Parse.Query(Trade);
query.find({
  success: function(trades) {
    for (var i = 0; i < trades.length; i++) {
    this_ref.items.offering = trades[i].get("offer")
    this_ref.items.needs = trades[i].get("wants")
     }
  }
});
}
}
```

This is the template/interface

```
export interface Items{
offering: string[];
needs: string[];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`items` is an object. Ionic `virtualScroll` requires an array to be passed in.

Do you mean to do:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="items.offering">      
  <ion-item *virtualItem="let item">
     {{ item}}      
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: well the reason i was trying to do {{item.offering}} and then take something else from the same query and make it {{item.needs}} i edited the above file to show